# No se imprimen datos de un array de objetos con un método filter

Tags: javascript

Quisiera saber porqué no se imprimen los autos que cumplen la condición con el método `includes()`
Este es mi código:

```
const auto1 = { marca:"Mercedes", modelo:"C63s", maxima:250, aceleracion:"3.3seg" };
const auto2 = { marca:"BMW", modelo:"M5CS", maxima:350, aceleracion:"3.3seg" };
const auto3 = { marca:"Porsche", modelo:"911Turbo", maxima:220, aceleracion:"3.3seg" };


        const array = [auto1,auto2,auto3];

        const filtro = (marca) => {
            marca=marca.toLowerCase();
            auto1= auto1.toLowerCase();
            auto2= auto2.toLowerCase();
            auto3= auto3.toLowerCase();
            
            let encontrados = array.includes(elemento => elemento.includes(marca));

            if (encontrados == undefined) {
                alert("Disculpe, no pudimos encontrar el auto que satisfasga su ingreso");
            } else {
                alert(encontrados);
            }
        }

        filtro(prompt("Ingrese el nombre que quiere buscar"));
```

No sé cuál puede ser el problema, no se me ocurre.

Comment: No sé entiende muy bien lo que quieres hacer. El parámetro máxima, contra que campo se debería comparar?

Comment: Cual es el objetivo del metodo filtro?
Recibe la velocidad maxima o el nombre del vehiculo?

Comment: Se tendría que comparar con el campo marca de los objetos auto1, auto2 o auto3.

Comment: Recibe la marca del vehículo

Comment: Probá haciendo esto:
`let encontrados = array.includes(elemento => elemento.marca==marca);`

Comment: Si queres buscar el vehiculo y mostrarlo creo que sería así 
`array.find(elemento => elemento.marca ===marca)`

Comment: No, sigue sin funcionar. No logro entender cual es el problema. Muchas gracias por la respuesta

Comment: Probé por la consola del browser tu código y funciona: [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8Csw.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8Csw.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes cosas que mejorar en el código.

- Primero, que estas tratando de reasignar valor a una constante, lo cual te dará error.
- Estas utilizando `toLowerCase` a un objeto, lo cual también te dará error.

Dicho esto, y dado que no especificas si la marca tiene que calzar por completo o parcialmente, te dejo tres opciones

```
const matchs = array.filter(i => i.marca === marca)
```

**[Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)**, la que te entregará un array con las coincidencias de la marca a buscar

```
const multiple = array.filter(i => i.marca.toLowerCase().includes(marca))
```

Una mezcla de `filter` e **[includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)**, la cual te sirve para encontrar elementos concordantes en tu arreglo, basado en una marca parcial, es decir que si tu buscas por la palabra **Merc** por ejemplo, esto te entregará el registro correspondiente a la marca **Mercedes**.

```
const onlyOne= array.find(i => i.marca === marca)
```

Y **[find](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)**, la cual te entrega un sólo objeto si cumple la condición.

Acá te dejo el ejemplo funcional para que lo analices.

```js
const auto1 = { marca:"Mercedes", modelo:"C63s", maxima:250, aceleracion:"3.3seg" };
const auto2 = { marca:"BMW", modelo:"M5CS", maxima:350, aceleracion:"3.3seg" };
const auto3 = { marca:"Porsche", modelo:"911Turbo", maxima:220, aceleracion:"3.3seg" };
    
const array = [auto1,auto2,auto3];

const filtro = (marca) => {    
  const matchs = array.filter(i => i.marca === marca)
  const onlyOne = array.find(i => i.marca === marca)
  const multiple = array.filter(i => i.marca.toLowerCase().includes(marca))
  
  console.log(`matchs => ${JSON.stringify(matchs)}`)
  console.log(`onlyOne => ${JSON.stringify(onlyOne)}`)
  console.log(`multiple => ${JSON.stringify(multiple)}`)
}

filtro('merc');
```

Cualquier duda, nos comentas.

Answer (score 2):

El método `includes` no recibe una función, sino el valor a buscar en el array. Lo que estás buscando realmente es el método `filter`:

```js
const autos =[
  { marca:"Mercedes", modelo:"C63s", maxima:250, aceleracion:"3.3seg" },
  { marca:"BMW", modelo:"M5CS", maxima:350, aceleracion:"3.3seg" },
  { marca:"Porsche", modelo:"911Turbo", maxima:220, aceleracion:"3.3seg" }
]

function autoToString(auto) {
  return auto.marca + " " + auto.modelo;
}

function filtraPorMarca(marca) {
  marca = marca.toLowerCase();
  let encontrados = autos.filter(auto => auto.marca.toLowerCase() === marca);
  console.log(encontrados.map(autoToString));
}


filtraPorMarca(prompt("Ingrese el nombre que quiere buscar"));
```

Answer (score 0):

No es necesario definir tantos objetos, solo tienes que definir un array, y dentro de ese array, los objetos que vos quieras. Luego, haces una función, con dos parámetros, y luego que la función tome esos parámetros que son ingresados como `prompt` y compruebe.
El código es:

```
const autos = [
            {marca: "Mercedes", modelo: "C63s", maxima: 250, aceleracion: "3.3seg" },
            {marca: "BMW", modelo: "M5CS", maxima: 350, aceleracion: "3.3seg" },
            {marca: "Porsche", modelo: "911Turbo", maxima: 220, aceleracion: "3.3seg"}
        ];
        const filtroBusqueda = (marca, maxima) =>{
            alert(autos.find(car => car.marca == marca));
            alert(autos.filter(car => car.maxima < maxima));
        }

        filtroBusqueda(prompt("Ingrese la marca que quiere encontrar"), prompt("Ingrese la velocidad máxima que quiere encontrar"));
```